# How to write correct executable_path of selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, path, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with python and tried to run chromedriver in my Windows PC.
I unpacked the zip file to several folder, listed in PATH.
However, the same error always appers: "'./chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see [https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home"](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home%22).
I`ve tried to put chromedriver.exe in several folders, listed in PATH, include system32 and Windows, but no luck.
Here is an example.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\\Users\\polikarpov\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApp\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\polikarpov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApp\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: already tried but SyntaxError appears: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: OK, can you try the edited option?

Comment: The common error appears now - ''Not in the path''

Comment: This obviously means `chromedriver.exe` file is not presented in C:\Users\polikarpov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApp\ folder

Comment: Have you find the problem?

Comment: No, just checked again: file is presented in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driverpath = Service('C:\\Users\\polikarpov\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApp\\chromedriver.exe') #add your own path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driverpath)
```

---

****EXTRA TIP****

If you want to run it in headless mode

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driverpath, options=option)
```

Comment: Same error appears unfortunately

Comment: @Vladislav what does the error say?

Comment: 'C:\Users\polikarpov\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApp\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern:

Seems like error has been caused by webdriver function update in newest version of selenium. After communicating with selenium community in chat, I`v found that Executable_path argument is already deprecated. Correct solution is usage of Service function. In my case it looks like this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
service = Service('C:\\Users\\Владислав\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options = options)
```